# Rails: Custom Create Method with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to create a method where, when a `user` first signs up via my `Devise` login, they input a score which then gets saved into the database twice (once as `g_score_start` and once as `g_score_current`.  This way later they can update `g_score_current` but the starting score always stays the same.

I currently have this in my custom `RegistrationsController`, but it's still not saving in the database:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super
    @user.g_score_current = @user.g_score_start
  end
  ...
end
```

Can anyone help me get this to save properly?

Comment: Where did you get the `@user` from?

Comment: @RSB, I assumed '@user' would be the user that's being created, but come to think of it that's probably immensely stupid.  How should I refer to the user that's being created?

Comment: I have added an answer, please try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case you should use `before_create` model callback instead, in `user.rb`

```
before_create :set_current_store

def set_current_store
  self.g_score_current = g_score_start
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Excellent!  That worked perfectly.  I am, however, getting some weird behavior for newly-created users that may or may not be related.  I created a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455709/rails-newly-created-user-showing-random-information-not-in-database) just in case, but if you're up for a challenge I'd love the help!

Comment: Actually, scratch that.  Once I got rid of the funky code I previously had and put yours in new users stopped behaving weirdly.  If you want to throw this in as an answer for the other question I'll select it there as well!

Comment: Glad that helped! :)